# Why Does Ubuntu present such a low resolution in a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox

I downloaded via virtual box Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I've never used Ubuntu before but wanted to give it a shot.  My host is an HP 2000 notebook pc, Intel R Core i3-3110M CPU.  Graphis say VESA: Oracal VM Virtualbox VBE AAdapter

I am booting from the hard disk on the virtual machine but the graphics look horrible.  Everything is so big, the icons..and it doesn't even look clear...like a bit blurry.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Again, I a new to using Ubuntu so any help explained at like the kindergarten level would be helpful.

Comment: Did you install the VBox Guest additions in the guest?

Comment: Thanks guntbert.  How do I do that?  I have the VBOX guest additions ISO in storage tree, under Controller: IDE How do I install?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use higher resolutions (and for some other benefits as well) you need to install the guest additions. I take it from [the virtualbox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp11306688)

1. You need several packages beforehand: [build-essential [image: Install build-essential]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential) ( `sudo apt-get install build-essential` ) will pull in almost everything you need.
2. They recommend installing [dkms [image: Install dkms]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dkms)( `sudo apt-get install dkms` )
3. In the "Devices" menu in the virtual machine's menu bar, VirtualBox has a handy menu item named "Install guest additions", which mounts the Guest Additions ISO file inside your virtual machine.
4. use the output of `mount` to determine where the image is mounted (I expect `/dev/sr0`)
5. `sudo -i` gives you a root shell (after entering **your** password)
6. type `cd /dev/sr0` (or what is appropriate in your case)
7. type `sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` for the actual installation/build process to start (it will take some time)
8. end your root shell with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
9. log out of your session and then log in again (you could also reboot the system)

Now you will get a much better resolution and you will be able to resize the window with the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing this with the following:

- Devices -> Install Guest Additions CD Image -> Run
- Restart your virtual machine.